# Upload Image to Folder and send path to database in struts?

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts

Upload Image to Folder and send path to database  in struts?

Comment: Because you did initially not tag the question properly (so very few users see it) and because there are not many Struts users out here and also because your question is way too broad.

Comment: Thank  u Bauke Luitsen Scholtz could u give some ides for how to uoload an image to folder and insert physical path to table or please show the link of tutorial for this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at apache commons FileUpload http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html .

And perhaps this article will help you as well http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html .